# Safe to use static casting for performance in a unique virtual int type() for each instance?

Tags: c++, performance, polymorphism, dynamic-cast, static-cast

I have a dense hierarchy of polymorphic objects, each of which comes with a mandatory `virtual int type() = 0` method, which is manually written for every object.

The "safe" processing of the tree using `dynamic_cast` has a significant overhead, and as I already have a virtual method which will return a unique integer for each different type, I think it is safe to use an unsafe static cast. But I might be overlooking something, for example in cases of multiple inheritance or something else which may cause a misalignment which may cause the static cast to "crash"?

The hierarchy is traversed on base class level by different contexts, each of which has a custom way of interpreting the data, so for each object there is `switch (type)` and "do according to type" where the casting takes place.

The `type()` virtual is declared in the "utmost-base-class", which is always first in the inheritance.

Comment: As long you know the derived types, and they are derived from your base in the calling code, there's no disadvantage (regarding _safety_) using the `static_cast<>`.

Comment: Consider using the visitor pattern.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I think that's what I am reinventing in my own way.

Comment: especially if you do something like `if (obj.type() == LEAF_ABC) {static_cast<ABCType &>(obj).ABCMethod(); ...} else { /* handle similar to how dynamic_cast would have returned NULL */ }`  If you are setting up a number of big switch statements based on switch(obj.type()), then you probably need to add some virtual methods.

Answer (score 1):

According to the **standard** 5.2.9/2 the static cast you intend to do is **safe,  under the condition** that the base class in not a virtual base class, nor a base of a virtual base class.

Here the example provided in the standard:

```
struct B { };
struct D : public B { };
D d;
B &br = d;
static_cast<D&>(br); // produces lvalue to the original d object
// Note that this works because B is not a virtual base class
```

So unless you use multiple inheritance with virtual bases, it's ok.

But be carefull if you have somethink like:

```
struct B { };
struct D1 : public virtual B { };
struct D2 : public virtual B {}; 
struct E : D1, D2 {};  
E e; 
B *pb=&e;   //
static_cast<E*>(pb);   // ouch !!! This would not safe 

D1 *pd1 = &e; 
static_cast<E*>(pd1);   // but this would be ok
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the use of `dynamic_cast` with `static_cast` in your code as long as you make sure that conversion is actually doing the right thing. `dynamic_cast` involves some run-time overhead which is missing from `static_cast`.

However, I am not sure if there could be some implication of replacement in case of multiple/virtual base classes. I had encountered a scenario where I stored addresses returned by `operator new` and then on later checking it showed that address is not present.

```
//Get the address from new
void* operator new(size_t size);

//Store this address in list.
std::list<void*> rawAddresses;

//Function to check if address is present
isAddressPresent(void* address)         <<< This vomitted error when I passed object of
                                        <<< class which has virtual base.
```

Comment: Pointers to polymorphic classes have a tendency of not being the same as the pointer to the "most derived type", especially in multiple inheritance. There's also the whole problem of ensuring that you *always* store pointers in `rawAddresses` after `new` and *always* remove them after `delete`, not to mention race issues if you ever introduce threads.

Comment: So you want to say "Pointers to polymorphic classes have a tendency of not being the same as the pointer to the "most derived type" is true also in case of single inheritance while considering that you are converting these pointers to void*.

Comment: In practice, single inheritance will generally point to the same address because the compiler can know the exact layout of the virtual table given a single inheritance type. However, as far as I'm aware, it's not guaranteed. This is why `static_cast` is *not* recommended. If you use `dynamic_cast` to/from `void*` then sure it'll work -- assuming the compiler is *able* to `dynamic_cast` from `void*` to whatever type it is. Most I've used will not, however, because `void*` could be anything (including a type which doesn't have RTTI such as `int`!).

Answer (score 0):

Using static_cast in this way should be fine -- as long as you can guarantee that you're casting to the correct type. I would highly recommend a simple unit test which can verify that you don't have any `type()` collisions (eg, a copy-paste error could cause `SubclassB` to have the same `type()` id as `SubclassA`) -- just add all types to a map and check for collisions. Further, you can safe-ishly create helper functions which guarantee the correct type (depending on your usage pattern). Here's an example.

```
// g++ test.cpp --std=c++11
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <stdexcept>

class Base {
public:
    virtual int type() = 0;

};

class SubClassA : public Base {
public:
    virtual int type() override { return 1; }
};

class SubClassB : public Base {
public:
    virtual int type() override { return 2; }
};

class BaseConversion {
public:
    BaseConversion(Base *ptr) : _ptr(ptr) {}
    Base *_ptr;
    template<typename T>
    operator T() const {
        throw std::runtime_error("invalid Base * type()");
    }
};

template<>
BaseConversion::operator SubClassA*() const {
    if ( _ptr->type() != 1 ) {
        throw std::runtime_error("type() not SubClassA");
    }
    return static_cast<SubClassA*>(_ptr);
}

template<>
BaseConversion::operator SubClassB*() const {
    if ( _ptr->type() != 2 ) {
        throw std::runtime_error("type() not SubClassB");
    }
    return static_cast<SubClassB*>(_ptr);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Base *ptr = new SubClassA();

    try {
        SubClassA *a = BaseConversion(ptr);
    } catch (const std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    try {
        SubClassB *b = BaseConversion(ptr);
    } catch (const std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It does mean you'd need to specialize a template for each subclass of `Base`. However, this also means you can write a unit test for each which exercises the conversions and helps ensure that you always check for the correct `type()` id and convert to the correct subclass (by having to only write `SubClassA` once in the pointer declaration/allocation instead of also in the `static_cast`).

This won't help you (performance wise) if you do something like this:

```
switch (ptr->type()) {
case 1:
    SubClassA *a = BaseConversion(ptr);
    /* do stuff with a */
    break;
case 2:
    SubClassB *b = BaseConversion(ptr);
    /* do stuff with b */
    break;
}
```

...since you'd effectively be checking type() twice. However, as long as `type()` just returns an integer and doesn't have to do calculations to figure out what type it is, the performance shouldn't be *terrible* if you do (there are far worse things you could do). Note that, because of static_cast, this does effectively remove any `const`ness of the given pointer! There are probably ways to resolve that but I'll leave that as a further exercise for you since I'm lazy.